# Fetching data from server

Tags: php

i can use https to post data to apache2 server, is there any way of using https to retrieve some data from the server, running php script or something to return

Thanks

Comment: Please be a bit more verbose about what you want to do. "Fetch data from server" is incredibly hazy.

Comment: "some data" and "something to return" don't help any either

Comment: sorry, data would be some fields from a database. A time and a name from the database

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use a https GET request to retreive data.

Comment: Hi, thanks but in my php script on the server i know how to get the GET variables like this $_GET['var'];

But how do i return the data as an array back to the client from my php script

Comment: That depends on what output format you want. Try print_r($array) for arrays or var_dump($object) for objects. If you want JSON output take a look at json_encode() in the PHP manual.

Answer (score 1):

you might want to use CURL for this ([php.net manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php)).

Answer (score 0):

not sure what you are trying to say but you can always use this

```
$f=file_get_contents('https://example.com');
```

Answer (score 0):

If your code is on the same server as the data you might not need an https connection. You can probably just read the data. If you need to use a web-API, check its documentation for how to connect over a secure connection.

Answer (score 0):

I found an example here: http://blog.taragana.com/index.php/archive/how-to-use-curl-in-php-for-authentication-and-ssl-communication/

(sorry but I couldn't post more than one hyperlink)